# How can I create an accociation to a specific key using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have my models all set up, and I have a foreign key from one table to another using the tables ID. I also want to have the url property as a foreign key, but whenever I include "type: DataTypes.STRING', I get the following error

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: (conn=195, no: 1215, SQLState: HY000) Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

When I don't include the datatype, it adds the FK, but as an integer. How can I create a FK that specifically references the URL property?

Thanks

```
categories.belongsTo(categoriesTop, {
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'topCategoriesUrl',
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        referencesKey: "url"
    }
});
```

Categories_top schema

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../dbconfig');

const categories_top = db.define('categories_top', {
  url: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  subtitle: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  image: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false
});

module.exports = categories_top;
```

categories schema

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../dbconfig');
const topCategories = require('./category_top');

const categories = db.define('categories', {
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  subtitle: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
  },
  url: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  image: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false
});



module.exports = categories;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you define the `topCategoriesUrl` column as a string in the `categoriesTop` model and not on the foreign key definition?

Comment: I've done that as well. The URL in categoriesTop is set to a string, which is why I think that my error is being caused by a syntax error when trying to reference the url column. I think that it's just referencing the ID column, and not the url column

Comment: can you post both tables' model?

Comment: I added them to the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `url` in `category_top` as a primary key or a unique constraint, like this:

```
const categories_top = db.define('categories_top', {
  url: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true, // Either define it as a primary key
    unique: true // OR as a unique constraint
  },
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  subtitle: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  image: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false
});
```

Read more about foreign keys [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).

Comment: That isn't working. I tried adding both PK and UK to url, but have the same issue. 
I understand what FKs are, but when you're using an ORM, some of the rules change...